# Check if one option is selected in dynamic radiobuttonlist in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have 4 radiobuttonlist in page that are added dynamically. I have to check if 
one of the options is checked in 4 of them in jquery. How can it be done? I tried to add same class ("rb1") to each radiobuttonlist in c# and tried for following code but could not get desired result.

```
$('table.rb1 input:radio').each(function () {
     var checked = $(this).find('input:radio:checked');
     if (checked.length == 0) {
         alert("All questions are mandatory !!! ")
         result = false;
         return;
     }
 });
```

Html code is as follow:

```
<table id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl34" class="rb1" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl34_0" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl34" value="1" />
            <label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl34_0">excellent</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl34_1" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl34" value="2" />
            <label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl34_1">good</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl34_2" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl34" value="3" />
            <label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl34_2">average</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl34_3" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl34" value="4" />
            <label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl34_3">not relevant</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply check if the `length` of `table.rb1 input[type="radio"]:checked` is equal to `0` for each `table`:

```js
$('#check').on('click',function(){
  $('table.rb1').each(function(){
    if($('input[type="radio"]:checked',this).length == 0) alert('None checked');
  });
});

$('#reset').on('click',function(){
  $('table.rb1 input[type="radio"]').prop('checked',false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="rb1" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" value="1" /><label>excellent</label></td>
    <td><input type="radio" value="2" /><label>good</label></td>
    <td><input type="radio" value="3" /><label>average</label></td>
    <td><input type="radio" value="4" /><label>not relevant</label></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="rb1" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" value="1" /><label>excellent</label></td>
    <td><input type="radio" value="2" /><label>good</label></td>
    <td><input type="radio" value="3" /><label>average</label></td>
    <td><input type="radio" value="4" /><label>not relevant</label></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="rb1" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" value="1" /><label>excellent</label></td>
    <td><input type="radio" value="2" /><label>good</label></td>
    <td><input type="radio" value="3" /><label>average</label></td>
    <td><input type="radio" value="4" /><label>not relevant</label></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="check">Check</button>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

Comment: I have 4 radiobuttonlist.I have to check in each four of them that one option is selected.I have written html for only one radiobuttonlist .

Comment: very nice.Thank you so much.